# Where can I see in the Revolut Android application on which day of the month my amount of currency exchange is reset to 0?

Tags: 9.0-pie, revolut

I have a standard plan with Revolut, which means I can do up to 6kEUR of  currency exchange without any transaction each month.

Where can I see in the Revolut Android application on which day of the month my amount of currency exchange is reset to 0?

I use Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android S9.

(Disclaimer: this is not a hidden advertisement for Revolut. On the contrary I advise against using Revolut as overall the user experience is really bad with them)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It currently isn't possible to see in the Revolut Android application on which day of the month my amount of currency exchange is reset to 0. One has to go through the customer service chat to know the information.